# Is there a way calling a variable without declaring it

Tags: python, variables, linked-list

I'm learning a course of Data Structures and Algorithm. There's a quiz that request me to write some codes that describe Linked List type:

```
class LinkedList(object):
def __init__(self, head):
    self.head = head

def append(self, new_element):
    current = self.head
    if self.head:
        while current.next:
            current = current.next
        current.next = new_element
    else:
        self.head = new_element
```

The code above is the example that the course made for me. But there's something I don't understand is in the "while current.next" loop, it's clearly that the "current.next" variable hasn't been declared. I have   researched about the "next" thing but it's just about the next () method.
Here's the course if you interest: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud513/lessons/7117335401/concepts/78875247320923

Comment: Not enough information, is this the complete code? People cannot access the Udacity course without logging in. It would be helpful to now what `head` is supposed to be. Maybe it's `next` attribute has a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.next` attribute has to be provided by the thing you pass in when constructing the linked list and append objects to it.

Here is a very basic example of how this could work

```
class LinkedList(object):
  def __init__(self, head):
      self.head = head

  def append(self, new_element):
      current = self.head
      if self.head:
          while current.next:
              current = current.next
          current.next = new_element
      else:
          self.head = new_element

  #added for demonstration
  def output_values(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
      print(current.value)
      current = current.next

class LinkedObject:
  next = None
  value = None
  def __init__(self, val=None, nextObject=None):
    if nextObject:
      self.next = nextObject
    if val:
      self.value = val
  
ll = LinkedList(LinkedObject(5))

ll.append(LinkedObject(24))
ll.append(LinkedObject(332))

ll.output_values()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code you wrote down for me. By the way in the class Linked Object, in the __init__ function there are 2 parameters "val" and "next Object" that is set = None. Is setting those two with "None" necessary? Because I think that if we don't assign the values to those two, they will defaultly set = "None" right?

Comment: It is not completely necessary. The only reason why I am doing that is so I don't need to always define them when creating the object. Meaning that you can call the constructor without any parameters without any errors.